# CSS will-change attribute toggling

Tags: css, animation

After reading a [post](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/) on CSS Tricks I noticed an advice at the very end of the post

> it’s recommended to toggle on `will-change` just before an element or
>   property changes and then toggle it off again shortly after the
>   process is finished

As an example I have my css like so

```
.item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.item.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

My question is how exactly should I toggle the `will-change` property prior and after the animation? Should I create another class with the property and add it to an element before adding `.visible` or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

> it’s recommended to toggle on will-change just before an element or property changes and then toggle it off again shortly after the process is finished.

In your case, I would add a class with the `opacity: 0;` stuff that represents the state of `.item` as being hidden (`.hidden`), and assign `will-change` to that class instead of assigning it to `.item`. Then whatever it is that changes state to `.visible` can remove `.hidden` once the `opacity` transition is finished, which will remove the `will-change` definition and return it to the default state of `auto`

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var item = document.getElementById('reveal');
  item.classList.add('visible');
  var allDone = setTimeout(function() {
    item.classList.remove('hidden');
  },1000)
});
```

```css
.item.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.item.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
<div class="item hidden" id="reveal">ta-da!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is very close to what my only option was, also pulling 84kb of jq seems a little too much for class manipulation

Comment: @AntK `will-change` assumes you're going to use something like JS to change the state of an element after the page has rendered. In your example, you're adding a `.visible` class - how are you going to add that? The only other things where `will-change` would be useful that aren't modified via client side code state changes are changes made via pseudo classes, like `:hover` or `:target` or something. And you don't have to write jQuery, of course - I just did that here because it's easy, and assumed you could sort that out if you use it or not. Updated my answer with vanilla JS.